# How to get Next 4 digit number from Table (Contains 3,4, 5 & 6, digit long numbers)

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I found a good method of getting the next 4 digit number. 
[How to find next free unique 4-digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827649/how-to-find-next-free-unique-4-digit-number)

But in my case I want to get next available 4 or 5 digit number.
And this will change depending upon the users request. Theses number are not a key ID columns, but they are essential to the tagging structure for the business purpose.

Currently I use a table adabpter query. But how would I write a query. 
I suppose I could do a long iterative loop through all values until I see a 4 digit.

But I'm trying to think of something more efficient.

```
Function GetNextAvailableNumber(NumofDigits) as Long
'SQL Code Here ----
'Query Number Table

Return Long


End Function
```

Here's my current SQL:

```
'This Queries my View
SELECT MIN([Number]) AS Expr1
FROM  LineNumbersNotUsed

'This is my View SQL 
SELECT Numbers.Number
FROM Numbers
WHERE (((Exists (Select * From LineList Where LineList.LineNum =  Numbers.Number))=False))
ORDER BY Numbers.Number;
```

Numbers is the List of All available number from 0 to 99999, basically what's available to use.

LineList is my final master table where I keep the long and all the relevant other business information.

Hopefully this make sense.

Gosh you guys are so tough on new guys. 
I accidentally hit the enter key, and the question posted and I instantly get -3 votes.

Give a new guy a break will you! Please.

Comment: Finish your post before posting. :(

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not Your Free Promotional Site™](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128560/140505)

Comment: @Oded: The question is in the header (How to get next...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize in advance in case I overlooked something in your question.  Using your design, won't a query like this return the next unused 4 digit number?

```
SELECT MIN([Number]) AS next_number
FROM  LineNumbersNotUsed
WHERE
        [Number] > 999
    AND [Number] < 10000;
```

This approach is not adequate with multiple concurrent users, but you didn't indicate that is an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked to explains that what you need is a table with 2 fields:

```
Number     InUse
0000       No
0001       No
0002       Yes
0003       No
0005       Yes
```

Whenever a number is used/released, the table must be updated to set `InUse` to Yes/No.

Maybe I'm missing something, but from your explanation, and the SQL code you show us, it seems that you only have a table with a single field containing all numbers from 0 to 100000.
If that's the case, I don't see the usefulness of that table at all.

If I were you, and if I understand your need correctly, what you want is something like this:

1. First of all, create the table as above, with all running numbers from 0 to 100000, and a field for confirming if that number is used or not.
2. Initialise the `InUse` field with all the numbers already taken in your `LineList` table, something like:

   ```sql
   UPDATE Numbers SET InUse = True
   WHERE  Numbers.Number IN (SELECT LineNum FROM LineList)
   ```
3. Write a function `ReserveNumber(NumOfDigits as Integer) As Long` to find and reserve a 4-digit or 5-digit free number following this logical sequence:

   - Depending on `NumOfDigits` (4 or 5) get the result of one of the queries as  `LowestNumber`:

     ```
     SELECT Min(Number) FROM Numbers WHERE Number < 10000 AND NOT InUse
     SELECT Min(Number) FROM Numbers WHERE Number >= 10000 AND NOT InUse
     ```
   - Reserve that particular number to ensure it's not going to be used again:

     ```
     UPDATE Numbers SET InUse = True WHERE Number = @LowestNumber
     ```
   - Return  `LowestNumber`
4. Whenever

**Notes**: the logic above is a bit naive as it suppose that no two users will attempt to get the lowest number at the same time. There is however a risk that this may happen one day.
To remove that risk, you can, for instance,  add a `TakenBy` column to the `Numbers` table and set it to the current username. Then, after you have reserved the number, read-it again to ensure that the `TakenBy` is really updated by the current client. If not, just try gain.
There are lots of ways to do this. You can try to fiddle around table locks as well, but whatever your solution, make sure you test it.

Comment: That's helpful... Especially if i'm designing something that needs to accomadate alot of users. Thanks.